# Center divisions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on this plugin: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=97549:3:114050913757697:

It's an organisation chart plugin that you can drag and drop through the pink area window. You have to click in the green, Red or yellow area in order to drag and drop the chart.

[current plugin state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqBSj.png)

I have two linked issues on this plugin:

-The area that you can click to drag and drop are too small. In order to increase the clickable area I expend the red area (html code and css modification in the end of the post).

-Expending the clickable areas causes the area to unalign from the center of the pink window and I don't know how to center them. [Here is an exemple of unalignement when I enlarge red area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2fd1.png). You can find in the orange rectangle the css modification I made to get this result.

Relevant Html Code:

```
<div id="chart-container"> <!--Pink-->
    <div class="orgchart"> <!--Green-->
        <table>            <!--Red-->
            <tbody>        <!--Yellow-->
            ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code of those elements:

```
#chart-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 24px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
    border: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
    transition: margin-left .2s ease;
}

.orgchart {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 202px;
    min-width: 202px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-size: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px dashed transparent;
    padding: 17% !important;
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 51);
}
.orgchart table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20% !important;
}

.orgchart table tbody {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    text-align: center;
}
```

All those issues lead to this question:

How can I center an element in a window, with `transform: matrix` since it is this line that defines the position of the div in the window, regardless of the dimension of the element (the size of the chart depends on the inputed data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a better picture how matrix works in CSS translate. But if you dont want to, maybe most important is that by writing:

`transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 71, 51);`

is the same as:

```
transform: translateX(71px)
transform: translateY(51px)
```

And since your container div is set to 100% width, you cant set child element to centre so easily, since its starting position will always be at the left up corner. Maybe there is a trick in CSS to set centre position in percentage, but I dont know any.

And doing it in Javascript is pretty easy. Here is an example (you need to configure it according to your real values (parent container sizes, paddings etc.):

```js
var parentWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("container")).width);
var parentHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("container")).height);

var elementWidth = 50;
var elementHeight = 50;

var translateX = (parentWidth / 2) - (elementWidth / 2);
var translateY = (parentHeight / 2) - (elementHeight / 2);

var child = document.getElementById("child");
child.style.webkitTransform = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, ${translateX}, ${translateY})`;
```

```css
#container{
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it the best way or not, I am not sure, but it does the job done - centres element using `translate: matrix()` in parent container which is initialised without providing exact size values. Comment, please if something goes wrong etc.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/julius0615/ah40nLca/2/)

[Very nice info about CSS matrix](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/)